# Is there a node js code sample reflecting how to read multi line text within a table row using the Document AI form parser?

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I'd like to extract table data from a PDF file as done by the Try document AI demo. However, if a table row has multi line text within the same row, it's reflected as a separate row in my Json response. This is also reflected when using the Upload test document feature in the cloud console, as shown on the attached screenshot.[Cloud Console demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsuVU.png).

However, the Try document AI demo (https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/drag-and-drop) reflects the data correctly. [Try document AI demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QEHz.png). Is this due to different API versions being used?

Node js code - using document AI v1beta3 version with form parser processor;

```
 var dataTable;
      for (const page of document.pages) {
        //tables
        for (const table of page.tables) {
         dataTable = printTableInfo(table, text);
         if (dataTable) return { table: dataTable };
        }
      }
```

```
// printTableInfo function
    function printTableInfo(table, text) {
     let dataArray = [];
     
       for (let i = 0; i < table.bodyRows.length; i++) {
      let bodyRowText = "";
      for (const bodyCell of table.bodyRows[i].cells) {
        const bodyCellText = getText(bodyCell.layout.textAnchor, text); //
        bodyRowText += `${JSON.stringify(bodyCellText.trim())} | `;
      
      }
      dataArray.push({
        [`Data`]: bodyRowText,
      });
      }
    
      return dataArray;
     
    }
// getText function
    const getText = (textAnchor, text) => {
      if (!text || !textAnchor) return;
   
      if (
        (!textAnchor && !textAnchor.textSegments && !textAnchor.textSegments) ||
        (textAnchor &&
          textAnchor.textSegments &&
          textAnchor.textSegments.length) === 0
      ) {
        return "";
      }
      const startIndex = textAnchor.textSegments[0].startIndex || 0;
      const endIndex = textAnchor.textSegments[0].endIndex;

      return text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be related to which [processor version](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/manage-processor-versions) you are using.

[Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) has two Google-Managed versions:

- `pretrained-form-parser-v1.0-2020-09-23` (`stable`) [This is the default when creating a new processor]
- `pretrained-form-parser-v2.0-2022-11-10` (`rc`)

These versions may output different results due to changes in model quality.

The Try It Demo uses the `rc` version - You can see this on the "JSON" page in the app.

```
https://us-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/projects/224664002400/locations/us/processors/c2b2b49c83a94613/processorVersions/rc:process
```

[image: Form Parser Demo]

Since you're getting the results as you expect from the `rc` processor version, I'd recommend changing the default processor version for your Form Parser, or changing the request code to [send a request to that specific version](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#online-processor-version).